# C variable declaration in gcc compiler - compile time error

Tags: c

Assume the following C variable declaration:

```
int *A[10], B[10][10];
```

Of the following expressions:

1. `A[2]`
2. `A[2][3]`
3. `B[1]`
4. `B[2][3]`

Which will not give compile time errors if used as left hand sides of assignment statements in a C program.

A) 1, 2 and 4 only

B) 2, 3 and 4 only

C) 2 and 4 only

D) 4 only

I have tried this on a gcc compiler. I assigned the value '0' to all the above variables. Only the third one showed an error. I can't really understand the reason. Can someone please explain the reason?

Answer (score 6):

1. You can assign 0 to `A[2]`, because `A` is an array of pointers, and you can assign 0 to a pointer (it's a NULL pointer).
2. You can assign 0 to `A[2][3]`, because at this level you're working with the `int`.
3. You cannot assign 0 to `B[1]`, because `B` is an array of arrays, and 0 is a scalar.
4. See 2.

Comment: More accurately, for (3) you cannot assign arrays. Even if you used the C99 compound literal (§6.5.2.5) notation, you could not assign to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Break the declaration into:

```
int *A[10];
int B[10][10];
```

You can see that `A[10]` is really an array of *pointers*, while `B[10][10]` is an array of integer arrays. The reason why you cannot assign an integer to `B[1]` is because `B[1]` is supposed to be of type `int[]` (an array), and you can't overwrite it with an `int` value.

Assigning to `A[2]` works because you're just pointing that array element to some other value, in this case an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

1. A[2] = 0 is correct, because A[2] = NULL is obviously correct and NULL is defined as 0. However if you try some value other than 0, you should encounter some type transition error.
2. A[2][3] = 0 is correct, in terms of syntax, as this statement is understood by the compiler as * (* (A + 2) + 3) = 0; Or more clearly, consider it as "int* p = A[2]; *(p + 3) = 0";
3. B[1] is incorrect; the superficial reason is B[1] points to an array and you cannot assign an array; the essential reason is that B[1] is translated into some address value by the compiler, so it cannot work as a left value. Or one can consider it this way: There is no corresponding memory cell for B[1].
4. B[2][3] = 0 because this is how it works :)